# How to create EntityMapping object for Sentinel Alert Creation?

Tags: powershell, azure-sentinel

I'm trying to create Scheduled Sentinel Alert with Entity Mapping parameter using PowerShell command in Runbook.

Converted nested JSON to hashtable and have sent this table as entityMapping parameter. Added my code below. But facing issue while creating the alert using 5.1 version of PowerShell.

My code:

```
$json =  '[
  {
    "EntityType": "IP",
    "FieldMapping": [
      {
        "ColumnName": "FileHashCustomEntity",
        "Identifier": "Address"
      }
    ]
  }
]'


function Convert-PSCToHashTable
{
  param(
    $InputObject, 
    [int]$Depth = 5
  )

  if($Depth -gt 0){
    if($InputObject -is [System.Collections.IList]){
      return @($InputObject |ForEach-Object {Convert-PSCToHashTable $_ -Depth ($Depth - 1)})
    }

    if($InputObject.psobject.BaseObject -is [System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject]){
      $ht = @{}
      foreach($prop in $InputObject.psobject.Properties){
        $ht[$prop.Name] = Convert-PSCToHashTable $prop.Value -Depth ($Depth - 1)
      }
      return $ht
    }
  }

  return $InputObject
}
$object = ConvertFrom-Json $json
$hashtable = Convert-PSCToHashTable $object
echo $hashtable
New-AzSentinelAlertRule   -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -WorkspaceName $WorkspaceName  -QueryFrequency 1:00:00   -QueryPeriod 1:00:00 -DisplayName "TesS-2"   -Kind Scheduled   -Query "SecurityAlert | where TimeGenerated == '99'"   -Severity Low    -TriggerOperator GreaterThan -TriggerThreshold 10 -EntityMapping $hashtable
```

Output:

```
Name                           Value                                                                                    
----                           -----                                                                                    
FieldMapping                   {Identifier, ColumnName}                                                                 
EntityType                     IP                                                                                       


[BadRequest] : Invalid data model. [: Invalid length of '0' for 'FieldMappings'. 'FieldMappings' length should be between '1' and '3']
System.Management.Automation.ParameterBindingException: Parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified named parameters.
```

Tried with 7.1 PowerShell version. It worked fine but 5.1 is creating issue as we need to manually convert the JSON into hashtable:

```
$entities = $json | ConvertFrom-Json -AsHashTable
 
New-AzSentinelAlertRule   -ResourceGroupName "myResourceGroupName" -WorkspaceName myWorkspaceName"  -QueryFrequency 1:00:00   -QueryPeriod 1:00:00 -DisplayName "TesS-2"   -Kind Scheduled   -Query "SecurityAlert | where TimeGenerated == '99'"   -Severity Low    -TriggerOperator GreaterThan -TriggerThreshold 10 -EntityMapping $entities
```

Comment: It is something wrong with your parameters. I assume that the problem is with the QueryFrequency and -QueryPeriod parameters. They are from the datatype TimeSpan. Try to use (New-TimeSpan -Hours 1) instead of a string. 
Note I did not test it, it is only a guess

Comment: @guiwhatsthat .. edited the above post.. tried the same query with 7.1 version as it contains -AsHashtable parameter .. It worked fine. I'm seeing an issue in 5.1 version while converting json to hashtable and sending that as a parameter to EntityMapping